# I can't get mysql to return last row when using the aggregate MIN

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using MIN function in mysql to return the smallest value of a column - lets call it price, however i also wish to display various other columns for this particular row with the smallest value for price. So far i have the following:

```
SELECT underlying,volatility FROM shares
where (id,price) IN (
    SELECT id,MIN(price) FROM shares
    where DATE(issueDate) >= DATE(NOW())
    group by id
 )
```

This almost works however it returns more than one row, i only wish to display the last row, can anyone please assist me with this?

Comment: Use `LIMIT` to limit the number of rows returned

Comment: i have tried that but it only returns the first row, i need the last one

Comment: order by desc limit 1 should do it

Comment: yup i am trying that now, but order by what?

Comment: order by price desc limit 1?

Comment: can you show us your table schemma and a small sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: @godzilla. Do you have any column that is a unique identifier for each row? you are grouping by id on a MIN(price), so i assume id is not unique.

Comment: i think i have solved it Filipe, i will post my answer, perhaps you can double check to ensure it is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i have solved the problem, it takes a while to execute so i will start by adding a new index :

```
SELECT underlying,volatility,price FROM shares
where (id,price) IN (
    SELECT id,MIN(price) FROM shares
    where DATE(issueDate) >= DATE(NOW())
    group by id
) order by price asc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT underlying,volatility FROM shares
where (id,price) IN (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY price ASC), ',', 1) AS id,
        MIN(price) FROM shares
    where DATE(issueDate) >= DATE(NOW())
    group by id
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Having clause will do the trick, please check my solution

```
select volatility,underlying, min(price) as min_price  from shares
where DATE(issueDate) >= DATE(NOW())
group by issueDate
having min_price = min(price);
```

[fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b5ae/3)